# Meteor.js logout route won't redirect

Tags: meteor

I'm am trying to make my router redirect to my home route upon logout but meteor continually returns me to the meteor generated login form instead. Am I doing something incorrectly?

This is my router:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/logout', function(){
  var self = this;
  Meteor.logout(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('Error Logging out: '+ err);
      }
    self.redirect('/');
    // Router.go('home'); (Also tried this and didn't work)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out ... painfully obvious.

I've an `ensureSignedIn` function that checks the logged in status and redirects to the login form. The `logout` function was not included.

```
// LOGGED IN
Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', {
  except: ['home','logout']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also newbie in meteor. But the below code is works fine in my app. Hope it may help you a bit.

```
Router.route('home', {
  path: '/'
});
// After logout redirect by
Router.go('home');
```

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback @BlueBells. Still not certain why it isn't working but glad to see it's not your issue.